# Gravity property of TextView in xml does not center the text

Tags: android, xml

I have a `TextView` in a `LinearLayout`, width is set to `fill_parent` and height is set to `wrap_content`. When I apply the `android:gravity="center"` property in the `TextView`, then, instead of aligning text to `center`, the text begins from center. Moreover, when the `gravity` property is set to `"right"`, the text disappears, ie, it begins from the right end. I just started with learning android and I am just a beginner. I googled, searched on this forum, but could not find the solution. Please Help. My xml code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text View"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I know that changing the `layout_width` to `wrap_content` will solve the problem, but I want to know why this method isn't working. Because, this will solve the problem in the case of `TextView`, but it will stay a problem when working with `Button` as I wont be able to align the text in it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you post your output

Comment: try changing the width of textview to wrap_content

Comment: what do you want. the textview to appear at the center of the screen

Comment: `@Iftikar Urrhman Khan`, I wish I could post my output, but stackoverflow doesn't allow users to post images if they have reputation < 15 :(
`@MDMalik`, I want the text to be appeared at the center of the layout.

Comment: `@Basim Sherif`, I know that changing the `layout_width` to `wrap_content` will solve the problem, but I want to know why this method isn't working. Because, this will solve the problem in the case of `TextView`, but it will stay a problem when working with `Button` as I wont be able to align the text in it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the textview will fill the complete width and text will be centered if you want the textview itself to be centered change fill parent to wrap_content for width

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Comment: `@prvn`,I know that changing the `layout_width` to `wrap_content` will solve the problem, but I want to know why this method isn't working.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your code i copied your code and it is working fine. it is strange why it is behaving differently for you

Comment: `@prvn`, I too copied this code from an android tutorial. I wonder why it is not working for me

Comment: Got the Solution - Changing the API to Android 2.2 solves the problem

Comment: @prvn, I had the same problem with some text which started in the center of textview and any solution didn't solve it ... But after Eclipse restar it solved itself (I don't know why.). It may be the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was resolved by:

```
        android:gravity="center"
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `android:gravity="center"`, text will be centered in the element (if the `layout_width` is not set to `wrap_content`. If you do not get expected behavior, try restarting Eclipse and it works. [worked for me]